# binding data through jquery to table

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am using load on page scroll . from this link 
http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-data-while-Scrolling-Page-down-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASPNet.aspx

On page load it display's 10 record in form of table, I am binding unique id to table from database. Starting 10 row's bind id correctly , but after 10th row I see {source code}, Id on all table after 10th is same it's taking id on first table. I am using this table unique id for removing table when delete is done. 
I am also using a usercontrol inside this table. Usercontrol is behaving in the same way as table. After 10th row usercontrol repets id of first table. Here's my code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var pageIndex = 1;
    var pageCount;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            GetRecords();
        }
    }); 

    function GetRecords() {
        pageIndex++;
        if (pageIndex == 2 || pageIndex <= pageCount) {
            $("#loader").show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'CS.aspx/GetCustomers',
                data: '{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
        var customers = xml.find("Customers");
        customers.each(function () {
            var customer = $(this);
            var table = $("#dvCustomers table").eq(0).clone(true);
            $(".name", table).html(customer.find("Title").text());
            $(".city", table).html(customer.find("Description").text());
            $(".postal", table).html(customer.find("UserID").text());
            $(".country", table).html(customer.find("EmailID").text());
            $(".phone", table).html(customer.find("Status").text());
            $(".fax", table).html(customer.find("UserID").text());
                 $(".MainCommentscont", table).html(customer.find("ID").text());
                   $(".MainComments", table).html(customer.find("ID").text());

            $("#dvCustomers").append(table).append("<br />");
        });
        $("#loader").hide();
    }

    </script>
```

I want this ID  should bind with table(inside repeter) and usercontrol and should not repeat after 10th row.

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="dvCustomers">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomers" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;
                                border: dashed 2px #04AFEF; background-color: #B0E2F5" class="MainCommentscont" id='<%# Eval("ID")%>'>>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>

                                                <b><u><span class="name">
                                                    <%# Eval("Status")%></span></u></b>
                                                    </td>
                                          <td>
                                                <b>Desc: </b><span class="MainComments">
                                                    <%# Eval("ID")%></span><br />
                                                <b>Desc: </b><span class="city">
                                                    <%# Eval("Description")%></span><br />
                                                <b>User: </b><span class="postal">
                                                    <%# Eval("UserID")%></span><br />
                                                <b>Email: </b><span class="country">
                                                    <%# Eval("EmailID")%></span><br />
                                                <b>point: </b><span class="phone">
                                                    <%# Eval("Status")%></span><br />
                                                <b>Fax: </b><span class="fax">
                                                    <%# Eval("UserID")%></span><br />

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <br />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="bottom">
                <img id="loader" alt="" src="loading.gif" style="display: none" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem, you don't change table ID after clone. Could you try that?

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
        var xml = $(xmlDoc);
        pageCount = parseInt(xml.find("PageCount").eq(0).find("PageCount").text());
        var customers = xml.find("Customers");
        customers.each(function () {
            var customer = $(this);
            var table = $("#dvCustomers table").eq(0).clone(true);
            $(".name", table).html(customer.find("Title").text());
            $(".city", table).html(customer.find("Description").text());
            $(".postal", table).html(customer.find("UserID").text());
            $(".country", table).html(customer.find("EmailID").text());
            $(".phone", table).html(customer.find("Status").text());
            $(".fax", table).html(customer.find("UserID").text());
                 $(".MainCommentscont", table).html(customer.find("ID").text());
                   $(".MainComments", table).html(customer.find("ID").text());
//Change table ID
$(table).attr('ID',customer.find("ID").text());
//-
            $("#dvCustomers").append(table).append("<br />");
        });
        $("#loader").hide();
    }
```

Comment: It worked. But still having problem left related to user control describd above. I have user control inside that table row. That usercontrol is binding unique Id and display's result. It display's result correctly but after 10th row it repets first table id.  Here's usercontrol      <uc1CommentImages:ImagesComment ID="ucCommentImages" runat="server" sendingidforpic='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />. How Can I change it's ID after 10th row from jquery append currently I am  using this code inside function   $(".onlyteninnercomment", table).html(customer.find("ProblemID").text()); but not working for me

Comment: Obviously, I do not understand exactly what do you want. Why use repeater and jquery plugin and same time user controllor? If you want to display dynamic data, i suggestion for you, do not use repeater and user control. Directly use jquery plugin instead of repeater.

Comment: Sorry for not explaning properly. I useually code in .net c# ,having less knowledge about jquery .I am using Repeter control to dispaly data. Inside that repeter a usercontrol is placed . Usercontrol also have data as per ID. It display's right till first 10 row. After 10 row usercontrol takes id of first row. For example in facebook I am using repeter do display main comment and inner comment I am getting through usercontrol that bind by id on main comment. Hope you get's me.

Comment: This time I understood. Usercontrol is asp.net control so you can not create it dynamic with javascript. So you can not use usercontrol, you have to handle it in repetar after that in ajax response code. (if you cannot understand me do not worry about because english not my native language, i can explain again)

Comment: I placed html code on user control ,and for calling jquery I am provindng asp.x path. It's working for above 10 row's . How can I update this <uc1CommentImages:ImagesComment ID="ucCommentImages" runat="server" sendingidforpic='<%#Eval("ID") %>' /> line ID as per new row from this  $(".onlyteninnercomment", table).html(customer.find("ProblemID").text()); . I think it is similar to the problem of table. Do you have any other idea , to display inner data (facebook inner comment as per main comment id).

Comment: You cannot use usercontrol next 10 row. Because usercontrol asp.net component and it has to created by server side. You should change your way. Otherwise I can not think anything else.

Comment: Thanks man, you have sort out some of my issue, I implemented by server side, it's  working but having a small issue please look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251157/filling-nested-listview-on-proper-place-with-json  please look out this , m waiting , and Big thanks for your help in this post.